# How to generate the java class after modifying the .avsc file

Tags: java, avro

I have modified the data types of the fields in my avsc file to :

```
        {
          "name": "base",
          "type": ["null","double"],
          "default": null,
          "doc": "Base amount"
        },
```

Initially it was string type.

But the avro generated java classes are still having String even after Building the project in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Not clear what "building the project in eclipse" does, but you can use a Maven or Gradle Avro Plugin to read your schema and re-create a Java class